# Java unchecked warning issues with understanding how to fix

Tags: java, generics, exception, lambda

I am having hard time to understand the difference between two declarations on java generics.

lets say I have the following two interfaces

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CheckedFunction<T, R, E extends Throwable> {
   R apply(T t) throws E;
}
```

```java
public interface SomeInterface<DTO, E2 extends Throwable> {

    <E extends Throwable> CheckedFunction<Object, String, E> firstFunction();

    CheckedFunction<String, DTO, E2> secondFunction();
}
```

So now I created an implementation of those and an "unchecked" warning popped which is what I am trying to understand.

The implementation is the following

```java
public class TmpImpl implements SomeInterface<TmpObj, IOException> {

    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public CheckedFunction<Object, String, JsonProcessingException> firstFunction() {
        return objectMapper::writeValueAsString;
    }

    @Override
    public CheckedFunction<String, TmpObj, IOException> secondFunction() {
        return json -> objectMapper.readValue(json, TmpObj.class);
    }

    public static class TmpObj {
        String s;
    }
}
```

for this example I am using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` as it does exactly what I want and generates the warning.

So the firstFunction now has a warning

```
Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion. Found 'CheckedFunction<java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException>', required 'CheckedFunction<java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,E>
```

while the second is just fine.

Why is this happening ? I am clearly missing something which I haven't noticed in order to fix it!

note `JsonProcessingException` extends `IOException` (declaration: `public class JsonProcessingException extends IOException` )

Comment: Why did you parameterize `<E extends Throwable>` on `firstFunction`?

Comment: I want to show the difference. That if I put the generic as parameter (E) it will complain about the unchecked but if I use the generic on class (E2) it will not

Comment: why did you not try `public interface SomeInterface<DTO, E extends Throwable, E2 extends Throwable>  { CheckedFunction<Object, String, E> firstFunction();

    CheckedFunction<String, DTO, E2> secondFunction();
}` ?

Comment: That would work yes. I am trying to understand why the parameter is not working. @Naman . Just instead of making the same example with 2 interfaces + 2 implementations i combined them in one

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis because your interface expects a type hint at method level to identify the correct type match during inference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that your implementation is dictating `JsonProcessingException` whereas the interface allows for `E` to be inferred.

In other words, according to the interface, this should be possible:

```
SomeInterface<String, RuntimeException> runtimeExceptionSomeInterface = null;
CheckedFunction<Object, String, RuntimeException> function = 
                     runtimeExceptionSomeInterface.firstFunction();
```

This declaration:

```
<E extends Throwable> CheckedFunction<Object, String, E> firstFunction();
```

allows the caller to specify the concrete argument for `E`, which is exactly what I did in the above example (using `RuntimeException`).

However, your implementation is statically forcing `JsonProcessingException`:

```
public CheckedFunction<Object, String, JsonProcessingException> firstFunction() {
    return objectMapper::writeValueAsString;
}
```

That is to say you've disregarded the incoming `E` type argument and forcefully substituting it with `JsonProcessingException`.

---

In short, if you want the `firstFunction()` to be generic, then implement it accordingly:

```
@Override
public <E extends Throwable> CheckedFunction<Object, String, E> firstFunction() {
    return objectMapper::writeValueAsString;
}
```

However, the above fails `return objectMapper::writeValueAsString;` with an unhandled `JsonProcessingException`, which I suspect led to your implementation.

That simply means that your use of a generic `Throwable` parameter is wrong.

A first attempt at solving it would be to use `SomeInterface`'s `E2` variable:

```
interface SomeInterface<DTO, E2 extends Throwable> {
    CheckedFunction<Object, String, E2> firstFunction();
    CheckedFunction<String, DTO, E2> secondFunction();
}
```

which will solve the problem if implemented with:

```
class TmpImpl implements SomeInterface<TmpObj, IOException> {
    //...
    @Override
    public CheckedFunction<Object, String, IOException> firstFunction() {
        return objectMapper::writeValueAsString;
    }
```

However, you would still have a problem because it's not the user of `SomeInterface` that knows what exception will be thrown, but the implementation. This means that you should declare the exception type on the API, rather than making it a generic argument:

```
interface SomeInterface<DTO> {
    CheckedFunction<Object, String, IOException> firstFunction();
    //...
}

class TmpImpl implements SomeInterface<TmpObj> {

    //...

    @Override
    public CheckedFunction<Object, String, IOException> firstFunction() {
        return objectMapper::writeValueAsString;
    }
}
```

Which is to say that `SomeInterface` and its implementations know the range of exceptions to be dealt with, therefore the functions they return know of, in this case, `IOException` (which is selected because you know it includes `JsonProcessingException`, among other types)

Comment: Oh interesting. You are right with "which I suspect led to your implementation." as I was trying to have a "fine" control on which exception should be handled and not a general one ( Like `throws Exception` ). From what I read this cannot be done! Thank you for the answer